# Use php to write to create virtual host for apache

Tags: php, apache, permissions

I'm trying to write a script to create virtual host vor apache (CentOS 6.4 on AWS)
I tried on simple write:

```
$result = file_put_contents( '/etc/httpd/conf/vhosts/test.conf', 'teststring'); 
var_dump($result);
```

This is my permission and owner infomation:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache 34445 Jan 16 11:08 httpd.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache 13139 Aug 13 17:30 magic
drwxrwxrwx. 2 apache apache  4096 Jan 17 04:29 vhosts
```

But I still got this mesasge:

```
Warning: file_put_contents(/etc/httpd/conf/vhosts/test.conf): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/server-control/src/test.php on line 8 bool(false)
```

checking user by `ps aux|grep httpd`:

```
root      9804  0.0  0.0 246372  8712 ?        Ss   03:57   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    9808  0.0  0.0 247024  7972 ?        S    03:57   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    9809  0.0  0.0 248304  8644 ?        S    03:57   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    9810  0.0  0.0 247536  7872 ?        S    03:57   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    9811  0.0  0.0 247536  8020 ?        S    03:57   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    9812  0.0  0.0 247536  7876 ?        S    03:57   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    9813  0.0  0.0 247536  7948 ?        S    03:57   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

Please help!! Some server I can write to that folder by just change owner to `apache` but this one is not.

Answer (score 1):

I've Resolved this problem. Run `ls -laZ` and this is difference:

My local:

```
[root@localhost conf]# ls -laZ
drwxr-xr-x apache apache ?                                .
drwxr-xr-x apache apache ?                                ..
-rw-r--r-- apache apache ?                                httpd.conf
-rw-r--r-- apache apache ?                                magic
-rw-r--r-- apache apache ?                                ssl.crt
-rw-r--r-- apache apache ?                                ssl.key
drwxrwxrwx apache apache ?                                vhosts
```

EC2 Server:

```
[root@ip-172-31-0-37 conf]# ls -laZ
drwxr-xr-x. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 .
drwxr-xr-x. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 ..
-rw-r--r--. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 httpd.conf
-rw-r--r--. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 magic
drwxrwxrwx. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 vhosts
```

That mean EC2 Server is under `SELinux permission context`

To resolve problem, I ran `chcon -R --type=httpd_sys_content_t vhosts` and `ls -laZ` again:

```
[root@ip-172-31-0-37 conf]# ls -laZ
drwxr-xr-x. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 .
drwxr-xr-x. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 ..
-rw-r--r--. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 httpd.conf
-rw-r--r--. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 magic
drwxrwxrwx. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 vhosts
```

Difference is `httpd_sys_content_t` context on vhosts directory

Now apache can write to `/etc/httpd/conf/vhosts`

Please correct me if I did/understand anything wrong.